# reducing time complexity of 3 loops in python o(n^3)

Tags: python, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
for i in arrn:
    for j in arrn:
        for k in arrn:
            summ+=i*j*k
```

Help me reduce time complexity

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more context for someone to be able to even remotely start to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually the sum of the array's elements, to the power of 3. It could be implemented very easily:

```
summ = sum(arrn)**3
```

Which is O(n), since you access each of the elements once.